Как для события связать колесико мыши и любую клавишу в tkinter
Подскажите как в методе .bind создать связку <любая клавиша-MouseWheel> или KeyPress-e-MouseWheel?
import tkinter as tk
def func(event):
    label = tk.Label(text=event.keysym)
    label.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+500+500')
root.bind('<KeyPress-e-MouseWheel>', func)
root.mainloop()


Через один .bind не получиться сделать составные комбинации, но можно немного закостылять:
import tkinter as tk

def press(event):
    if event.keysym == 'e':  
        root.bind('<MouseWheel>', func)

def release(event):
    if event.keysym == 'e':
        root.unbind('<MouseWheel>')

def func(event):
    label = tk.Label(text=f"e + MouseWheel {event.delta}")
    label.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+500+500')

root.bind('<KeyPress>', press)
root.bind('<KeyRelease>', release)

root.mainloop()


странно что <Shift_L-MouseWheel> работает

@ВадимМотеюнас Shift, Ctrl, и Alt это всё специальные клавиши, по этому не удивительно, что для них сделали дополнительную логику ‍♀️
